# Get FileName from Command with Arguments

Tags: c#, command-prompt

Are there any .Net Methods that can extract the path and file name from a windows command string and not include the arguments?

```
var p = @"c:\somefolder\someConsoleApp.exe -k Something -i -user Bob"
```

I Tried using FileInfo, Path.GetFileName, and others, every time the object has the commands in it.

For example,

```
var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(p);
Console.WriteLine(fileName);
```

output

```
someConsoleApp.exe -k Something -i -user Bob
```

I want to get just "someConsoleApp.exe"  Preferably having access to the arguments to.

ProcessStartInfo might be able to do it somehow, but it has the same problem, FileName has the whole thing and Arguments is empty.

Comment: No, since your file **can** have the following name: `someConsoleApp.exe -k Something -i -user Bob`. You have to parse it by hand

Comment: Why don't you just seperate those string in the first place?

Comment: Do you have to handle potential spaces in the path of the exe?  And if so would the path be quoted?  That's really the only thing that might stop you from just splitting on space.

Comment: split string and get the first item, that should be name of your exe

Comment: @Pankaj unless the exe name has spaces in it.

Comment: @juharr, you can split by ".exe"

Comment: use this             string p = @"c:\somefolder\some Console App.exe -k Something -i -user Bob";
            string s = p.Substring(0, p.IndexOf(".exe") + 4);
            Console.WriteLine(p.Substring(0, p.IndexOf(".exe")+4));
            Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName( s));

Comment: @rashfmnb it's useless to post your answer as a comment

Comment: @rashfmnb, your code will fail if directory contains word "exe" in it.

Comment: why can't you do the following 
either -`Console.WriteLine(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName);` or `Path.GetFileName(Application.ExecutablePath)` or `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName` as simple `Google -Search on the following` could have saved you lots of guess work `how do i get the name of the current executable in c#`

Comment: Wow, so many responses, will go through them when I can.  Basically I am doing this in powershell.  The Get-WMIObject win32_server returns a pathname that is a command like above.  I was hoping for something easy that wouldn't require me to parse on it, but I might have to write some parse logic if nothing exists already in the framework to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Regex expression to handle with any filename (with spaces and periods)

```
string input = @"c:\somefolder\someConsoleApp.exe -k Something -i -user Bob";
var name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(input);
var match = Regex.Match(name, @"([A-Za-z0-9\-+=\s\.!%&$@{}\[\]'_])+\.([A-Za-z0-9\-+=!%&$@{}\[\]'_])+\s", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var shortname = match.Value;
if (shortname == "")
    shortname = name;
else
    shortname = shortname.Substring(0, shortname.Length - 1);
```

Even if you give the string

**c:\somefolder\some Console.App.bat -k Something -i -user Bob anotherApp.exe**

the result would be

**some Console.App.bat**

Comment: Filenames can contain a whole lot more of characters than alphanumeric and dash.

Comment: Added them and all other available symbols

Comment: Nice, this even works with @"c:\somefolder.14\something.exe\someConsoleApp.exe -k Something -i -user Bob";

Comment: Is there  way to get the Match to return the path and file name and only drop off the arguments?

Comment: Yes: var fullpath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(input) + shortname; Or you mean not to use IO.Path at all?

Answer (score 1):

For a windows command string like this:

```
var p = @"c:\somefolder\someConsoleApp.exe -k Something -i -user Bob";
```

You can get the real extension doing this:

```
var extension = Path.GetExtension(p).Split().First();
```

Then replace the extension to the real one:

```
var path = Path.ChangeExtension(p, extension);
```

And finally get the arguments:

```
var query = p.Replace(path, string.Empty);
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
extension =  .exe
path      =  c:\somefolder\someConsoleApp.exe
query     =  -k Something -i -user Bob
```

Comment: The command args could have extensions in them, which I think would break that no?

I'm think the best thing to do might be to split on the first period in the string, then get the first substring on the 2nd element up to the first space and that's the extension.  Then anything after that is arguments.

Comment: You are right, `GetExtension` and `ChangeExtension` takes the last `.*` as extension. but splitting by `.` and taking the 2nd element won't work for files like my.app.exe. Also note that `someConsoleApp.exe -k Something -i -user Bob` is a valid filename.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're always looking for `.exe` files you can go with this:

```
var p = @"c:\somefolder\someConsoleApp.exe -k Something -i -user Bob";            
var list = p.Split(new [] {".exe"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
var program = list.First() + ".exe";
var param = list.LastOrDefault();
```

- program => `c:\somefolder\someConsoleApp.exe`
- param => `-k Something -i -user Bob`

Comment: Exe could be anything.  The command string is returned from an API, I need to be able to extract the filepath and filename in all scenarios without knowing ".exe"

Answer (score -1):

use the following code to do this

```
        string p = @"c:\somefolder\some Console App.exe -k Something -i -user Bob";
        string s = p.Substring(0, p.IndexOf(".exe") + 4);
        Console.WriteLine(p.Substring(0, p.IndexOf(".exe")+4));
        Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName( s));
```

Comment: And what if the executeable was named "some Console App.exe"?

Comment: `Some ConsoleApp.exe` is a valid filename

Comment: @all for all those who make vote down here is the solution

Comment: Id suggest you may want to change it to .exe it looks for +4, as what if you had like psexec.exe

Comment: what about `myexe.exe` ?

Comment: fixed foe myexe.exe as well